# Infinity Constraint Matlab

Tags: matlab, constraints, infinity

I am using "patternsearch" to find the minimum objective function, but one of the constraints is in the form `x1+x2...xn <infinity`
I already know that `x1+x2...xn < 6` is written as:
`c=x1*x2*...xn -6` 
How would i include infinity?

Comment: This is not really a linear constraint. There should be no need to use it.

Comment: @knedlsepp the constraint that i am using is much complicated than this one, it includes limits and summations, so the main point of my question only lies in how to use the Infinity regardless of the type of the LHS of the inequality

Comment: The constraint is always true, any number is less than infinity. This isn't something you can write.

Comment: @AmiraAkra: `patternsearch` only provides linear constraints, i.e. restricting the search for the minimum to a `n`-dimensional halfspace given via the hyperplane `A*x = b`. In this sense your equation can't be *much more complicated* if you want to use `patternsearch`. Also: You don't get any new information from the 'constraint' of a linear combinations having to be smaller than infinity as this is valid for all points in `R^n`. This will also be true for polynomial constraints of higher order, which as I mentioned are not even possible with `patternsearch`. TLDR: `< infinity` is useless.

Comment: @knedlsepp so what should I use instead of patternsearch? if the constraints are non-linear

Comment: This will depend on the constraints. But you could start reading this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-equality-and-inequality-constraints.html Keep in mind though that if your constraints contain `infinity`, your math may need some more thought.

Comment: the constraint seems mathematically reasonable, but practically useless, since unless your `x1, .., xn` are assigned to `infinity`, or `value / 0`, is there anyway to get the `real infinity` values in Matlab?